# Ant Colony Optimization trouble

Tags: java, algorithm

I have this problem: build a tower formed with n colored cubes with given side. There can't be a cube with a small side on a cube with a bigger side and neither can't be two neighbor cubes with the same color. I'm trying to solve it using Ant Colony Optimization. The trouble that I have with it is that I don't know how to choose the next cube to move the ant on and leave pheromone on it.

```
Example: For the following cubes:
C1 - side = 5, Color = Red
C2 - side = 2, Color = Green
C3 - side = 10, Color = Blue
C4 - side = 1, Color = Red
the solution would be: C3, C1, C2, C4

This is what I've done so far:
```

Ant class:

```
     public class Ant {

        private int[] visited;
        private int size;

        public Ant(int size) {
            this.size = size;
            this.visited = new int[size];
        }

        public void clearVisited(){
            for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
                visited[i] = -1;
            }
        }

        public void visit(int index, int cube) {
            visited[index] = cube;
        }

        public int visited(int index){
            return visited[index];
        }

        public boolean contains(int cube){
            for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
                if(visited[i] == cube){
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Cube class:

```
    public class Cube {

        private int length;
        private String color;


        public Cube(int length, String color){
            this.length = length;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public Cube(String color){
            this.length = (int)Math.round(Math.random() * 200);
            this.color = color;
        }

        public int getLength(){
            return this.length;
        }

        public String getColor(){
            return this.color;
        }

        public void setLength(int length){
            this.length = length;
        }

        public void setColor(String color){
            this.color = color;
        }

        public String toString(){
            String str = "";
            str += "Cub: l = " + length + ", " + "c = " + color;
            return str;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object o){
            if(o == null){
                return false;
            }

            if(!(o instanceof Cube)){
                return false;
            }

            Cube c = (Cube)o;
            if((c.getColor().equals(this.getColor())) && (c.getLength() == this.getLength())){
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Cube Repository class:  here I store the cubes

```
    public class CubeRepository {

        private static ArrayList<Cube> availableCubes = new ArrayList<Cube>();

        public static void addCube(Cube cube){
            if(!availableCubes.contains(cube)){
                availableCubes.add(cube);
            }
        }

        public static Cube getCube(int index){
            return availableCubes.get(index);
        }

        public static int getSize(){
            return availableCubes.size();
        }
    }
```

The ACO algorithm:

```
    public class ACO {

        private int nrAnts;
        private int nrCubes;
        private Ant[] ants;
        private int currentIndex;
        private double[] pheromoneTrail;
        private double ph = 1; //pheromon trace on every cube at start
        private int alpha = 1;
        private int beta = 5;
        private int Q = 500;
        private double q0 = 0.01;

        public ACO(int nrAnts, int nrCubes){
            this.nrAnts = nrAnts;
            this.nrCubes = nrCubes;
            ants = new Ant[nrAnts];
            pheromoneTrail = new double[nrCubes];
        }

        public void createAnts(){//creeaza toate furnicile
            currentIndex = 0;
            for(int i=0; i < nrAnts; i++){
                ants[i] = new Ant(nrCubes);
            }
        }

        public Ant getAnt(int index){//return an ant
            return ants[index];
        }

        public void setupPheromoneTrail(){ //sets pheromone trail for every cube at start
            for(int i=0; i < nrCubes; i++){
                pheromoneTrail[i] = ph;
            }
        }

        public void placeAnts(){ //place every ant on a cube
            for(int i=0; i < nrAnts; i++){
                ants[i].visit(currentIndex, (int)(Math.random() * nrCubes));
            }
            currentIndex++;
        }

        public int selectNextCube(Ant ant){
            if(Math.random() < q0){
                int cube = (int)(Math.random() * nrCubes); //pick a random cube
                while(!ant.contains(cube)){
                    if(CubeRepository.getCube(ant.visited(currentIndex-1)).getColor().equals(CubeRepository.getCube(cube).getColor())){
                        cube = (int)(Math.random() * nrCubes);
                    }
                }

                return cube;
            }

            return 1; //I didn't return a proper value
        }

        public void MoveAnts(){ //move every ant on another cube
            while(currentIndex < nrCubes){
                for(int i=0; i < nrAnts; i++){
                    ants[i].visit(currentIndex, selectNextCube(ants[i]));
                }
                currentIndex++;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You mean that you want to replace the current `selectNextCube` method? What's wrong with it? (I would have expected a `while(and.contains(cube))` (without negation), but did not yet completely read and understand the code)

Comment: @Marco13 The ants must select another cube and then place pheromone on them. That's what I don't know how to do. SelectNextCube(Ant ant) is where I want the ant to move on another cube. The function is incomplete because I didn't quite know how to move the ant.

Answer (score 1):

Without having understood the whole program (it's far too much to quickly read it and find an answer): You may select a random cube that has a different color than the previous one with a pseudocode like this

```
private static final Random random = new Random(0);
public int selectNextCube(Ant ant)
{
    Cube previousCube = CubeRepository.getCube(ant.visited(currentIndex-1));
    List<Cube> allCubes = obtainAllCubesFromCubeRepository();
    List<Cube> sameColor = obtainAllCubesWithSameColorAs(previousCube); 
    allCubes.removeAll(sameColor);

    // EDIT>>>: You might also need this:
    allCubes.remove(computeAllCubesAlreadyVisitedBy(ant));
    // <<<EDIT: You might also need this:

    int index = random.nextInt(allCubes.size());
    Cube nextCube = allCubes.get(index);
    return indexFor(nextCube);         
}
```

BTW: I'd **strongly** recomment to **not** use `Math.random()`. It returns an unpredictable random value. Debugging a program that involves `Math.random()` is horrible. Instead, you should use an instance of `java.lang.Random`, as shown in the above snippet. You may call `random.nextDouble()` in order to obtain `double` values like with `Math.random()`. Additionally, you may call `random.nextInt(n)` to obtain `int` values in the range [0,n). The most important thing is: When you create this instance as `new Random(0)` then it will always return the same sequence of random numbers. This makes the program predictable and makes it possible to really debug the program. (If you want an "unpredictable" random number sequence, you can instantiate it as `new Random()`, without a random seed).